# how to show/hide panel on dropdown change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have nested panel. If a field is checked the panel one is visible. on dropdown change event i want to display panel2 inside panel 1 without refresh page but on dropdown change event panel1 is hiding

By code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Panel1 {
            width: 2000px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkRepeat").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#Panel1").show(1000);
            } else {
                $("#Panel1").hide(1000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Starts on :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Repeat" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRepeat" runat="server" />


            <br />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Repeats : " Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnList" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpdwnList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>Daily</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Weekly</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Monthly</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Repeat on :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Sun" runat="server" />S
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Mon" runat="server" />M
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Tue" runat="server" />T
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Wed" runat="server" />W
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Thur" runat="server" />T
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Fri" runat="server" />F
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Sat" runat="server" />S
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpdwnList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />

                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Ends : " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ScheduleAutomation.aspx.cs" Inherits="ScheduleAutomation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #Panel1 {
            width: 2000px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkRepeat").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#Panel1").show(1000);
            } else {
                $("#Panel1").hide(1000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Starts on :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Repeat" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRepeat" runat="server" />


            <br />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Repeats : " Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnList" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpdwnList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem>Daily</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Weekly</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Monthly</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Repeat on :" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Sun" runat="server" />S
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Mon" runat="server" />M
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Tue" runat="server" />T
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Wed" runat="server" />W
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Thur" runat="server" />T
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Fri" runat="server" />F
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Sat" runat="server" />S
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpdwnList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />

                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Ends : " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


    </div>
</form>
```

**CODE behind**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            chkRepeat.Checked = false;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    protected void drpdwnList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        if (drpdwnList.Text == "Weekly")
        {
            Panel2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
            Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you do `dropdown` change `event` on client side with `jquery`, if changing the visibility of the panel is the only thing you are doing on selection changed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need an update panel just to show or hide a panel, as it will post full page to server to process(it increase on request/response cycle).
You can remove Update panel.
Just use Jquery to do it easily

just include below code with your Jquery Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkRepeat").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#Panel1").show(1000);
            } else {
                $("#Panel1").hide(1000);
            }
        });

        $("#drpdwnList").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#Panel1").show(1000);
                $("#Panel2").show(1000);

            } else {
                $("#Panel2").hide(1000);

            }
        });
    });
```